# Passing BASIC authentication data into a spring ws client

Tags: spring, web-services, soap, spring-ws

I have a web service whose server uses basic http authentication to grant access

Web service itself has its own authentication username and password

WS is accessible using SOAP UI after setting the required parameters

I am not developing a UI client which would use the spring to access the web service

my question is How to I send the HTTP authentication that is entered by the user while opening the page to the web server so that he gives me access to the webservice

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The current spring ws documentation has an exmple of this here (chapter 6.1) :
http://docs.spring.io/spring-ws/site/reference/html/client.html#client-transports

I quote the interesting part of the configuration:

```
<bean id="webServiceTemplate" class="org.springframework.ws.client.core.WebServiceTemplate">
  <constructor-arg ref="messageFactory"/>
  <property name="messageSender">
    <bean class="org.springframework.ws.transport.http.HttpComponentsMessageSender">
        <property name="credentials">
            <bean class="org.apache.http.auth.UsernamePasswordCredentials">
                <constructor-arg value="john:secret"/>
            </bean>
        </property>
    </bean>
  </property>
  <property name="defaultUri" value="http://example.com/WebService"/>
</bean>
```

Last version of Spring WS I used was some time ago (1.x), but you can tap into pretty much anything the Apache Commons HTTPClient API has to offer using Spring WS.
When using the WSTemplate system, then the overriding point is the WSMessageSender. But the suggested method above allows to do all directly from Spring configuration.

In your scenario, you could provide an implementation of the UsernamePasswordCredentials that either has a callback to ask the user for the credentials, or have them injected otherwise.

Comment: In this example the username and password were sent as plain text , in my situation , I need to send the ones that the user has entered

Comment: Yes but nothing prevents you to build the `UsernamePasswordCredentials` on demand and set it on the fly on your `messageSender` instance. (Your `webServiceTemplate` should then probably be a `prototype`bean, so that you'd get a new one each time, passing in the relevant configuration when you know it). An alternative implementation would be to create your own subclass of UsernamePasswordCredentials that does a database lookup (or equivalent) to find the credentials where you actually store them.

Comment: Is it possible to retrieve the username and password which the user entered when he was requested at the opening of the website ?

Comment: It is possible to pass in anything that you have access to.
The question, then, is twofold : 1) does the website's authentication scheme give you access to the clear text password ? (a HTML form does or HTTP basic scheme do, an HTTP Digest or NTLM do not...). If not, that's a "game over". 2) If 1 is a yes : how do you access this information ? That is dependant on your implementation (Container based ? Spring Security ?...).
Anyway, this is a different question altogether, that has deep security ramifications you should be aware of.